# Vue 3 - Make the specific class properties reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

Is there any possibility to make some properties of the class instance reactive?

In the MobX it's fairly easy to do:

```js
class Doubler {
    constructor(value) {
        makeObservable(this, {
            value: observable,
            double: computed,
        })
        this.value = value
    }

    get double() {
        return this.value * 2
    }
}
```

But it looks like impossible to do it in Vue.

1.The most closest result that I get is the following result:

```
class Doubler {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = ref(value)
        this.double = computed(() => this.value.value * 2) // Ugly
    }
}
```

The computed code is ugly and it's using also differs:

```
const doubler = new Doubler(1)
double.value = 2 // No way!
double.value.value = 2 // That's it! Ugly, but that's it.
```

2.I can pass the created object to `reactive` function, but it make **all properties** reactive and it doesn't affect the internal implementation and it still will be ugly.

Is there any way to reproduce MobX approach in Vue?

Comment: You could pass a property that is reactive into your class' constructor like [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/reactivity-through-external-class-instances-functions-instances-and-objects/48750/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve it with classes. With objects though, the closest thing I can think of is something like this:

```js
function createDoubler(value) {
  const doubler = reactive({ value })
  doubler.double = computed(() => state.value * 2)
  return doubler
}

const doubler = createDoubler(4)
doubler.value // 4
doubler.value = 5
doubler.double // 10
```

EDIT: After giving it another thought I came up with the following solution:

```
class Doubler {
  constructor(value) {
    this._state = reactive({ value });
  }

  get value() {
    return this._state.value;
  }

  set value(value) {
    return this._state.value = value;
  }

  get double() {
    return this._state.value * 2;
  }
}
```

If you want to use `ref` instead of `reactive`:

```js
class Doubler {
  constructor(value) {
    this._value = ref(value);
  }

  get value() {
    return unref(this._value);
  }

  set value(value) {
    return this._value = value;
  }

  get double() {
    return this.value * 2;
  }
}
```

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-field-hzpll?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: `ref(value)` will make it work incorrectly due to ref unwrapping when Doubler instance becomes reactive, probably unintentionally