# Is there a way to make a class for customRef in Vue.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In the documents for Vue.js, it allows creating custom refs:

https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#customref

This is done by providing an object with getter/setter methods. What I'd like is to have a custom class where I can change the class properties and access them in the getter/setter.

The examples for customRef only use properties that don't change externally to the ref instance, for example the timeout property in useDebouncedRef in the above link. What I'd like to do is this kind of thing:

```
class AppCustomRef {
    public property;
    private _value;

    constructor(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }

    get() {
        if (this.property === true) {
            return this._value;
        } else {
            return -this._value;
        }
    }

    set(newValue) {
        this._value = newValue;
    }
}

const appPropertyRef = new AppCustomRef(100);
const myCustomRef = customRef(appPropertyRef);
appPropertyRef.property = false;
```

customRef takes the get/set functions from the passed object and assigns them to properties, which removes them from the scope of the passed object so property references using 'this' are undefined.

It uses CustomRefImpl here:

https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/reactivity/src/ref.ts#L297

That class isn't exported in the package unfortunately so I can't just extend it and I've tried implementing a copy of it but it ends up depending on multiple nested classes and functions that also aren't exported from the module.

Comment: Can you clarify how is it supposed to work? Notice that customRef is a *ref*, meaning that it's an object with the only public "value" key that is treated in a special way with ref unwrapping. If you need multiple keys that aren't "value", this is a misuse of refs. On a higher level this could be `reactive({ foo: computed({ get()..., set() })`

Comment: In the above github link, there are a few ref types like CustomRefImpl, ObjectRefImpl that conform to interface type Ref<T>, which requires a value key. I wanted to make a custom class like those that I could store properties on to modify the behaviour of the value (only value needs to be reactive, not the properties, modifying the properties triggers a value change). Using reactive() on a custom class works - reactive(new AppCustomRef()).

Comment: it would be an interesting exercise but where does the requirement to make it a ref come from? As mentioned, a ref is supposed to have only value property. This `myCustomRef.foo = 1` in a template will be compiled to `myCustomRef.value.foo = 1`, that's why you're trying to do is unconventional. If you have a specific case you need this for, consider explaining it, there could be idiomatic ways to implement this

Comment: I want a class that behaves like a ref so I can store additional properties and functions. There are a couple of other stackoverflow pages that are similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510120/vue-3-make-the-specific-class-properties-reactive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77457603/reactive-typed-class-in-vuejs3-with-typescript. The first one has a post that puts a ref inside a class, that's what I ended up doing, a reactive class instance gave warnings about recursive changes. Ideally I would just have extended customRefImpl and added extra functionality to it.

Comment: The vue.js docs have an example - https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#customref. In the useDebouncedRef function, they have a timeout that delays the property being set. However, it's not so easy to change the delay value after the ref has been created because there's no place to store properties. It would need to be a separate object that stores any custom properties.

Comment: ut why a ref and not just reactive object/class? Could be XY problem. The point of a ref is that it can be unwrapped, and the value can be fully reassigned, e.g. be nullable. You're breaking the concept of vue ref unwrapping this way. " because there's no place to store properties" - this is the reason I'd consider it an unrelated case, you could make delay param a ref there too to be able to change it from the outside, but I suppose you intended to make it more flexible

Comment: "reactive class instance gave warnings about recursive changes" - can you clarify? Reactive classes are known to have pitfalls in vue, could be that you shouldn't use a class at all. Notice that RefImpl classes are a different thing that works in its own way

Comment: "you could make delay param a ref there too to be able to change it from the outside, but I suppose you intended to make it more flexible". Just being able to change properties from outside would be enough but ideally store the properties on the same object. I can't make a ref instance with a variable inside, I can only make a wrapper class that contains the properties and the ref. This works, it just means explicitly accessing the ref for watchers. As you say, ref type probably isn't intended to be used like this, although it's not clear what a customRef can be used for without variables.

Comment: The recursive error I got with the reactive class was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75575139/keep-always-getting-maximum-recursive-updates-exceeded-in-my-component-with-n. This happened doing any kind of property assignment in the class. Using reactive() seems very hard to keep under control unless it's used on basic object literals. Reactive classes are not easy to work with. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894487/vue-3-reactivity-not-triggered-from-inside-a-class-instance

Comment: customRef is for a ref with custom behaviour, e.g. value conditioning like you tried, but only for one value, or debounced ref from the mentioned example. "wrapper class that contains the properties and the ref" - this results in this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76699032 , you'll have to use markRaw everywhere on class instance to make sure it works correctly. Not using classes is the best way, they have several pitfalls with vue reactivity